# How to pass object reference to another object?

Tags: javascript, function, reference, this, typeerror

example:

JS file:

```
function Controller() {
 self = this;

 self.createObject = createObject;
  function createObject() {
   new ObjectTest(self);
  }

 self.createAlert = createAlert;
 function createAlert(text) {
  alert(text);
 }
}

function ObjectTest(controller) {
 this.controller = controller;
 this.controller.createAlert("test");
}
```

---

HTML Document - object is constructed and method is executed

```
<body onload="new Controller.createObject()">
```

---

This would give the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'createAlert'
```

Answer (score 3):

When constructing an instance, you need to add parenthesis :

```
<body onload="new Controller().createObject()">
```

But you can simplify your controller and use the more standard construct :

```
function Controller() {
 self = this;
 self.createObject = function(){
   new ObjectTest(self);
 };
 self.createAlert = function(text) {
  alert(text);
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is interpreted as a namespace, so it tries to create an instance of the `Controller.createObject` function (there is none). Parenthesis are everything, you want

```
(new Controller).createObject()
// or
new Controller().createObject()
```

instead of

```
new Controller.createObject()
// which is like
new (Controller.createObject)()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parenthesis after `Controller`. You wrote:

```
<body onload="new Controller.createObject()">
```

That basically means *"create a new instance from `Controller.createObject`"* where you meant *"create a new instance of `Controller`, then call `createObject()`"*:

```
<body onload="new Controller().createObject()">
```

Also, it seems that `Controller` is more like a singleton or a "static class". You could actually avoid to create a new instance then, just using a simple Object:

```
var Controller = {
    createObject: function () {
        return new ObjectTest(this);
    },

    createAlert: function(text) {
        alert(text);
    }
}
```

And then from your code:

```
<body onload="Controller.createObject()">
```

Hope it helps.